# Change URL display - index.php with query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm trying to rewrite the displayed url in the browser to clean up a messy one.  I'm looking to just make it look nice, not do any redirects.

Here is the url formatting:

`https://website.org/folder/video/index.php?v=name&l=time`

and I would like it to still go there^ but display this:

`https://website.org/folder/video/`

I have searched through many similar questions, and none of the answers gave me what I'm looking for (I'm testing them [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) )
I also tried altering and trying to mess with other peoples' answers to fit my situation, but nothing seems to work.

Anyone know what I should try?  I am coming to realize that this might be more complicated than just an .htaccess file.  But any tips are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: I always suggest others to take advantage of Yaf(Yet another framework), it provides an entire solution of MVC, rewriting, routing and etc.

Comment: So from @RhapX's reference... Am I attempting to use .htaccess and mod-rewrite incorrectly?  Is this then not a thing that can be done?  If so - not at all?  or just not in this way?

Comment: @MichaelS no, I am not saying that. I'm saying there is already another reference that you can learn from to accomplish what you need, while understanding it at the same time.

Comment: @RhapX  I appreciate the link, and I do want to understand, not just be told.  But, I guess what I meant was... From having read through that reference you linked to, I understand that I may be attempting to use .htaccess and mod-rewrite incorrectly.  I would like to know if I am understanding that correctly.  If so that would explain why this has been so difficult for me to figure out, also I would then have to reword or resubmit my question.